# Changing the fore color of a label when hovering over the label

Tags: c#, devexpress, mousehover, onmousemove

I am trying to change the color of a label's text when I hover over it. I tried putting the command in the previewmousemove event but this doesn't work.

```
    private void hand_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
            xrLabel260.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        }
```

After this did not work, I tried to use the mouseenter/mouseleave events to change the color.

```
    private void xrLabel260_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        xrLabel260.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;

    }

    private void xrLabel260_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xrLabel260.ForeColor = Color.Black;

    }
```

This did not work either. How could I change my code so that it will work? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The previewmousemove is firing but there doesn't seem to be a way to use the mouseenter and mouseleave events in the devexpress designer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do something like this in your xaml:
EDIT: I have modified this to show how it fits into a main window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="My Label">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am new to this program. Would this go in the MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. If this still isn't clear send me your code and I will give you a hand. My email is in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't add event handler (register mouse events for label) for it:

```
xrLabel260.MouseEnter += xrLabel260_MouseEnter;
```

Most logical place to do it is in form's load routine.

Edit: for WPF you can have something like this in XAML (question had EventArgs instead of MouseEventArgs, I thought it was for WinForms):

```
<Label x:Name="xrLabel260" Content="Label" MouseEnter="xrLabel260_MouseEnter"/>
```

...and then in code-behind:

```
    private void xrLabel260_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        xrLabel260.Foreground =  Brushes.BlanchedAlmond;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using WPF not winforms. Where would I put this?